# Function only works on <pre> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div,pre').mouseup(function (e) {
        window.onkeydown = function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 81) {
                var gottext = getSelectionText();
                var apiurl = "http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=";
                var tofind = apiurl.concat(gottext);
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET", tofind, true);
                xhr.onload = function (e) {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                        if (xhr.status === 200 && gottext != "") {
                            console.log(xhr.responseText);
                            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            var whattodo = confirm(response.list[0].word + "\n\nDEFINITION: \n\n" + response.list[0].definition + "\n\nEXAMPLE:\n\n" + response.list[0].example + '\n\nPRESS "OK" TO VIEW ADDITIONAL RESULTS');
                        } else {
                            console.error(xhr.statusText);
                        }
                    }
                    if (whattodo == true) {
                        var textret = getSelectionText();
                        var pageurl = "http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=";
                        var togoto = pageurl.concat(textret);
                        console.log(togoto);
                    }
                };
                xhr.onerror = function (e) {
                    console.error(xhr.statusText);
                };
                xhr.send(null);
            }
        };
    })
});
```

OK, so I have this code which is supposed to get the text the user has selected, and then search for it on Urban Dictionary when the Q key is pressed.  However, it only seems to work when the selected text it a  element.  How can I get it to work on any type of text, regardless of element?

Demo with `<pre>`: http://jsfiddle.net/BQSJ3/180/

Demo with `<p>`: http://jsfiddle.net/BQSJ3/182/

Thanks!

Comment: There's no need for the `mouseup` event at all.  See this http://jsfiddle.net/BQSJ3/186/

Comment: Patrick Q has the right idea. Having to hover over it as well as highlight it is redundant. Not that I'm trying to redesign your UI... ;)

Comment: This is a very interesting idea by the way, I really like the concept.  It opens up some interesting user interaction possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

if you are wanting it to work on any element you can just change the selector to work on mouseup of the document:

change

```
$('div,pre').mouseup
```

to

```
$(document).mouseup
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work on any element just use the wildcard `*` selector.

```
 $("*").mouseup(function (e) { }
```

you could also try this...can't exactly vouch for the functionality:

```
$("*:not(:empty)").mouseup(function (e) {}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BQSJ3/184/

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to work with the p tag, shouldn't you have it included here:

```
$('div,pre').mouseup(function (e) {
```

?

This one works for me, if I am hovering over the selected text and then press "q"

http://jsfiddle.net/BQSJ3/185/

Comment: Actually, if OP wants it to work anywhere (without enumerating every possible element), that line and the related closing line can be removed.

Comment: Yes, the mouseup part seems to require that the mouse actually be hovering over the selected text or it will not fire.